# Однако(,) если будешь по-английски говорить, я в тебе заинтересован-таки

Tags: запятые

Нужна зап.?

`Однако(,) если будешь по-английски говорить, я в тебе заинтересован-таки.`

`Но(,) если будешь по-английски говорить, я в тебе заинтересован-таки.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[У Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140#pp140),** **пункт 5 (2,3)** решение зависит от вида союза:

1. После союза ***НО*** выбор делается по наличию **паузы** после союза НО, что определяется **по КОНТЕКСТУ**. При постановке  запятой придаточное предложение **в интерпозиции**  логически **подчеркивается**, например:

*Ты пока меня еще мало заинтересовала. Но, / **если будешь по-английски говорить,** / я в тебе заинтересован-таки.*

*Я тебя пока еще мало знаю. **Но если будешь по-англИйски говорить,** / я в тебе заинтересован-таки.*

2. После союза ***ОДНАКО*** запятая обычно ставится:

*ОднАко, / **если будешь по-англИйски говорить,** / я в тебе заинтересован-таки.*

Comment: Может, это «обычно» значит, что, если я на *если* ставлю, как Макс написал, ударение, не надо запятую?

Comment: Это неверно, сэр! Ударение не падает на служебные слова! Но оно падает на те слова в фонетической фразе, которые мы хотим выделить. Или же на конец фонетической фразы.

Comment: *Если будешь хорошо себя вести, дам на чай. Однако(,) éсли же будешь по-плохому, дам по балде-с!*

Comment: Если будешь хорошо себя вести, / дав на чАй. ОднАко(,) éсли же будешь по-плохОму, дам по балдЕ-с!

Comment: Нужна запятая?!

Comment: Здесь-то её можно из-за интонации не ставить! Или нужно всё-таки ставить?

Comment: Грамматическая пауза переходит в произносительную, но на письме обозначается запятой по-прежнему. Чисто грамматический принцип, такое встречается.  По большому счету перестройка интонации в сложных конструкциях происходит постоянно, но не все это видят, к сожалению.  А это приводит к разным проблемам.

Comment: А в каких случаях тогда запятая после _однако_ НЕ ставится?

Comment: Интонационный анализ – это действенный метод, но надо хорошо его освоить. Как?  Просто слушать  и сравнивать знаки, паузы, ударения.  Паузы и ударения связаны: больше пауза – больше ударение, и наоборот. К примеру, мы считаем: вводные слова выделяются паузами, запятыми, ударением. Но это не те ударения и паузы, которые характерны для основных структур  в предложении.  Если НО выделяется запятой, то  будет произносительная (небольшая пауза), а если не выделяется, то паузы. нет никакой.

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта возможны:

***Однáко, если будешь по-английски говорить, я в тебе заинтересован-таки*** (1);

***Однако éсли будешь по-английски говорить, я в тебе заинтересован-таки*** (2);

***Нó, если будешь по-английски говорить, я в тебе заинтересован-таки*** (1);

***Но éсли будешь по-английски говорить, я в тебе заинтересован-таки*** (2).

В вариантах, помеченных цифрой 1, делается ударение на первом союзе (ударный слог помечен), т. е. ты как бы его **выделяешь интонацией** и ставишь тем самым на первый план.

В вариантах, помеченных цифрой 2, ударение делается на **втором союзе (*если*)**, а первый (*однако*/*но*) пропускается ударением.

---

Вывод: ударение, сделанное самим автором, решает пунктуацию.